# meaning of Nietzsche's sentence:

Tags: meaning

I would appreciate it if you give me a simple explanation of the Nietzsche citation in this following paragraph:

> Nietzsche instead believed that we must look beyond hope. We must look beyond values. We must evolve into something “beyond good and evil.” For him, this morality of the future had to begin with something he called amor fati, or “love of one’s fate”:
>
> > “My formula for greatness in a human being,” he wrote, “is amor fati: [ed: my problem is with the following]
> >
> > that one wants nothing to be different, not forward, not backward, not in all eternity. Not merely bear what is necessary, still less conceal it—all idealism is mendacity in the face of what is necessary—but love it.”

Comment: This might be better on philosophy stack exchange! :-)

Comment: Which English word, phrase, or grammatical construction is used here in a way that needs to be explained? Providing an explanation of the overall philosophical point of the paragraph would be outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Please explain me the following sentence:

Not merely bear what is necessary, still less conceal it, but love it.

Comment: Some things are necessary. Don't try to simply endure them. Even less that that, do not try to hide them. Instead, openly embrace them. Love the necessary.

Comment: [What is AMOR FATI? What does AMOR FATI mean? AMOR FATI meaning, definition & explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbFBy4FX_ic)

Comment: The [original quote](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amor_fati) is "Meine Formel für die Größe am Menschen: das Notwendige nicht bloß ertragen, noch weniger verhehlen, sondern es lieben". That's actually very straightforward, transparent, simple. The English translation above is needlessly flowery and convoluted. Strip it down to its bare essentials. Or really just the title: Love your fate. That is all you need.

Comment: I appreciate for that helpful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That one wants nothing to be different, not forward, not backward, not in all eternity. Not merely bear what is necessary refers to Stoics. Therefore, Nietzsche says: **Don’t just bear fate (like Stoics)**.

Still less conceal it— all idealism is mendacity in the face of what is necessary refers to Leibniz. Therefore, Nietzsche says: **Don’t conceal it (like Leibniz)**

**Nietzsche says neither bear fate like Stoics nor conceal fate like Leibniz but love it!**

Source: https://www.artofmanliness.com/2018/01/01/eternal-return-ultimate-new-years-resolution/,http://privatewww.essex.ac.uk/~beatrice/Nietzsche%20and%20Amor%20Fati.pdf

*Hope, this helped :)*

Comment: It was very helpful and i am going to understand it. Thanks a lot. :)